# I am getting error when running code for a leftjoin of two tables named "data" and lookups"

Tags: dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I am getting the below error when trying to join two tables using `dplyr`. Can you please review the code and advise if there's something wrong?

```
data %>% 
  left_join(Lookups, by ="asset class")
```

Error

```
Error in UseMethod("left_join") : 
  no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Comment: Are you sure that both `Lookups` and `data` are a dataframes? The error message indicates that one of those is classified as a function. Can you provide the data here? If it's a lot of data, then you can just do `dput(head(data))` and `dput(head(Lookups))`, and paste the results into your original question.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGillreath-Brown, I managed to locate the root cause for the error. my code is now running smoothly.